# CRUD VUE JS PUT METHOD DOESNT WORKS

Tags: vue.js, crud, put, v-data-table

**Why does my edit button in a vue data-table not work?** The method creates a new line in the table. I want do edit a line.

**template**

```html
<!-- DIALOG PARA EDITAR USUARIO -->
<v-dialog v-model="editarDialog">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="text-h5">Editar Pessoa</span>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="pessoa.nome"
              label="Pessoa*"
              required
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="pessoa.idade" label="Idade*"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="editarDialog = false">
        Fechar
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="editarPessoa"> Salvar </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions></v-card
  ></v-dialog
>
```

**script**

```js
function botaoEditarPessoa(item) {
  state.pessoa = Object.assign({}, item);
  state.dialog = true;
}

async function editarPessoa() {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      url: "http://localhost:3000/update",
      method: "put",
      data: state.pessoa,
    });
    state.pessoa = res.data;
    await getData();
    state.dialog = false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I need to understand why the line ins't being edited. Please, help me find the error

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow. What this `getData()` does? And can you share more of the data-table component? When do you call `botaoEditarPessoa()` ?

Comment: @RaphaelMarques 
 async function getData () {
   try {
        const res = await axios({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/list',
          method: 'get'
        })

Comment: @RaphaelMarques
function botaoEditarPessoa (item) {
      state.pessoa = Object.assign({}, item)
      state.dialog = true
    }
Called here:
 <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }" >
     <v-icon small class="mr-2"
        @click="botaoEditarPessoa(item)"
      > mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you're creating a new `Object` every time you open the model to edit it. Then your put method probably identifies it as a new `Pessoa`, and instead of editing it, it's creating a new object.

I suggest you look into your PUT method, to see if he's identifying this object as an already created or a new one.

Comment: app.put('/update', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body // { id: 1, nome: "fulano de tal", idade: 32323 }
  const pessoa = pessoas.filter((e) => e.id === body.id)

  if (pessoa.length > 0) {
    const index = pessoas.findIndex((e) => e.id === body.id)
    pessoas[index] = body

    res.send(pessoas[index])
  } else {
    res.send({ error: "O id da pessoa informada não foi localizado" })
  }
})

Comment: Is it correct? @RaphaelMarques

Comment: When you are sending the request to the back end, it's creating a new entry there? That's probably what is happening, otherwise when you run `getData()` it shouldn't bring a new line.

Comment: and on your code, there's no reason to set the response of the PUT method to the `state.pessoa` (`state.pessoa = res.data;`). Because you're calling your endpoint to return the up-to-date list.

Comment: Yes. A new line is being created. 
But, now look. Still doesnt working

async function editarPessoa () {
      try {
        await axios({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/update',
          method: 'put'
        })
         state.dialog = false
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

Comment: The correct code: 
async function editarPessoa () {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/update',
          method: 'put',
          data: state.pessoa
        })
        state.pessoa = res.data
        console.log(state.pessoa)
        await getData()
        state.editarDialog = false
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

And the correct dialog to open : editarDialog
Now it works.
Thank you for the attention!!!